# OAuth2 component scopes

Tags: oauth2, jwt, federation

I'm currently implementing a system which consists of a collection of apps.  Similar to the way [Microsoft 365 consists of Word, Excel, etc](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/products-apps-services).

Ideally I'd like to log in once, then navigate between apps.  However, each app requires different (JWT) claims to work.  The system also needs to be able to federate with external auth servers.

What is the best way to support this?

- Single token with all the possible scopes?
- Each app requesting a new token with the scopes it requires?
- Something else?

Comment: Each app should request its own JWT token with its own configured Oauth2 client.

Comment: @defalt - that makes sense.  However, presumably that would mean a separate login (inc. username/password) when the user navigates between apps.

Is there a way to provide a more seamless authentication experience?

Comment: No. The user will login once at Oauth2 provider's webpage. This is why it is called single sign-on (SSO).

Comment: @defalt Ok got it.  Missed the fact that they'd all share the same provider.  I know that with different (federated) providers you get prompted for each site.  E.g. Even if I'm signed into this site using Google, it'd need to select "Continue with Google" on another site.  So, different clients using the same (direct) provider don't get hit with the prompt? **Edit:** Wait... that doesn't sound right - surely I could log in/out of each site independently.  If I'm logged out of both, I've got two logins to do regardless of provider.

Comment: The point of federated login is to enter username and password only once. Once you are logged in, if a web app redirects you to the provider, you won't have to reenter your credentials because you are already logged in there. The provider will immediately redirect you back.

Comment: Yeah, true.  Guess the user will just have to put up with a "Continue with <ID provider>" between each app.  If you want to add that in the form of an answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks